# MONGODB TLS/SSL Handshake failed in Replica Set with 3 Nodes Deployed with Docker-Compose

Tags: mongodb, ssl, docker-compose, tls1.2, replicaset

So I cant initiate a replica Set to work with TLS, when i try to deploy it with docker compose on my local machine.
When I go on a mono.mongors1 I try to make

```
    rs.initiate({
   _id : "mongors1",
 members:
  [
     { _id : 0, host : "mongo.mongors1 " , priority : 1},
     { _id : 1, host : "mongo-2.mongors1" , priority : 0},
     { _id : 2, host : "mongo-3.mongors1" , priority : 0}
   ]
    })
```

work, but I keep getting an error that the SSL Handshake failed. Error:

```
SSL Handshake failed. The server is configured to only allow SSL connections
```

When I exclude following from the Docker-Compose file

```
 `    - --tlsCertificateKeyFile=/security/certs_thorben/mongodb_node_1.pem
      - --tlsCAFile=/security/certs_thorben/ca.pem  
      - --tlsMode
      - requireTLS`
```

it works so the Error is coming from the TLs Certificate. I certificate with this Script

```
    openssl req -nodes -out ca.pem -new -x509 -keyout ca.key
# Create Certificate Requests
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -keyout mongodb_node_1.key -out mongodb_node_1.csr
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -keyout mongodb_node_2.key -out mongodb_node_2.csr
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -keyout mongodb_node_3.key -out mongodb_node_3.csr

# Signiere Certifikats
openssl x509 -req -in mongodb_node_1.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 00 -out mongodb_node_1.crt
openssl x509 -req -in mongodb_node_2.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 00 -out mongodb_node_2.crt
openssl x509 -req -in mongodb_node_3.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 00 -out mongodb_node_3.crt

# one pem file at the end
cat mongodb_node_1.key mongodb_node_1.crt > mongodb_node_1.pem
cat mongodb_node_2.key mongodb_node_2.crt > mongodb_node_2.pem
cat mongodb_node_3.key mongodb_node_3.crt > mongodb_node_3.pem
```

I define the common-name as follows: "*.mongors1"
It should work i guess cause i make an host alias in the docker-compose file for each node with ".mongors1" at the end.

This is how my docker Compose-File looks like.

```
    mongors1n1:
    container_name: mongors1n1
    networks:
      default:
          aliases:
            - mongo.mongors1  
    image: mongo_cluster:latest
    command: 
      - --shardsvr
      - --replSet
      - mongors1 
      - --dbpath 
      - /data/db
      # - --keyFile=/mongodb_keyfile
      - --tlsCertificateKeyFile=/security/certs_thorben/mongodb_node_1.pem
      - --tlsCAFile=/security/certs_thorben/ca.pem  
      - --tlsMode
      - requireTLS
      - --port
      - "27017"
      - --bind_ip_all
    ports: 
      - 27017:27017
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mounted/shards/primary1/db:/data/db
    depends_on:
      - mongors1n2
      - mongors1n3
    environment:
      - PRIMARY_SHARD=1
  mongors1n2:
    container_name: mongors1n2
    networks:
      default:
          aliases:
            - mongo-2.mongors1  
    image: mongo_cluster:latest
    command: 
      - --shardsvr
      - --replSet
      - mongors1 
      - --dbpath 
      - /data/db
      # - --keyFile=/mongodb_keyfile
      - --tlsCertificateKeyFile=/security/certs_thorben/mongodb_node_1.pem
      - --tlsCAFile=/security/certs_thorben/ca.pem
      - --tlsMode
      - requireTLS
      - --port
      - "27017"
      - --bind_ip_all
    ports:
      - 27027:27017
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mounted/shards/secondary1/db:/data/db
  mongors1n3:
    container_name: mongors1n3
    networks:
      default:
          aliases:
            - mongo-3.mongors1  
    image: mongo_cluster:latest
    command: 
      - --shardsvr
      - --replSet
      - mongors1 
      - --dbpath 
      - /data/db
      # - --keyFile=/mongodb_keyfile
      - --tlsCertificateKeyFile=/security/certs_thorben/mongodb_node_1.pem
      - --tlsCAFile=/security/certs_thorben/ca.pem
      - --tlsMode
      - requireTLS
      - --port
      - "27017"
      - --bind_ip_all
    ports:
      - 27037:27017
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mounted/shards/secondary2/db:/data/db
```

Do you guys have any idea to make the TLS Encryption work, on localhost with a replica-Set. Or have any idea what i do wrong here?
Thanks